# Unable to execute Wolfram script by calling a package

Tags: windows, command-line

I am working on a script which loads a package called `test`. When I try to run the same from my command line, I am seeing my input printed without execution.

Notebook execution:

```
Needs["test`"];
test["foo"]`
```

> `Output1`

Command line execution:

```
Needs["test`"];
test["foo"]
```

> `test["foo"]`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is the package on your `$Path`? Use `FindFile` to see if Mathematica can find it.